# Android query with "in" operator not working

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following code:

```
public void UpdateMessage(String[] mlst) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try
            {
                String sql="update messagesmaster set rstamp = 1 where mid in (" + mlst + ") ";
                statement = conn.createStatement();
                statement.executeUpdate(sql);

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

In this mlst is array of strings having 7 elements in it.

I wanted to form my query like:

```
String sql="update messagesmaster set rstamp = 1 where mid in ("sagar","dhanorkar","Ganesh") ";
```

But unfortunatly with above attempt its not working.

I am using sqlserver 2008 r2

Plese guid me.

Comment: You need to first convert your array of strings into single CSV string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `String[].toString()` is not the same as concatenating all elements to a valid SQL string.

Try this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("update messagesmaster set rstamp = 1 where mid in (");
for (int i = 0;i < mlst.length; i++) {
    if (i>0) sb.append(", ");
    sb.append("'").append(mlst[i]).append("'");
}
sb.append(")");
String sql = sb.toString();
```

For more sane SQL usage (in terms of performance and security) use this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("update messagesmaster set rstamp = 1 where mid in (");
for (int i = 0;i < mlst.length; i++) {
    if (i>0) {
        sb.append(", ?");
    } else {
        sb.append("?");
    }
}
sb.append(")");
String sql = sb.toString();
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, mlst);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Android query with “in” operator not working

Since you are not using parametrized statements but hardcoded solution you need to wrap values into single quotes:

```
where mid in ('" + mlst + "')
```

I don't like your approach. It won't work also because your mlst is array. It's not much human readable and dangerous. Generally is recommended (and also i recommend it) to use parametrized statements which are much more safe and human readable.

Placeholders (?) must be generated dynamically in your case.

**Example:**

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder("Update Test set col = value where mid IN(");
for (int i = 0; i < mlst.length; i++) {
   b.append("?");
   if (i < mlst.length - 1) {
      b.append(",");
   }
}
b.append(")");

PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareQuery(b.toString());
for (int i = 0; i < mlst.length; i++) {
   ps.setString(i + 1, mlst[i]);
}
int result = ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: He is not using SQLite I think. (sql-server-2008-r2)

Answer (score 1):

`mlst` is a `String[]` object which is an array. If you try to concatenate it to a string you'll end up using its `toString()` method which is not what you want. You have to produce a `String` object from it by looping through the array:

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
for(String str : mlst) {
    b.append(str);
    b.append(", ")
}
// you have to remove the last , or do not add it in the first place
```

There is a design flaw here however: you are concatenating arbitrary values to a query which can result in an SQL injection. I whink you should sanitize `mlst` before you use it as parameters blindly. I remember that there is a parameter binding solution in Android, you should consult the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for :

```
String[] mlst = { "sagar", "dhanorkar", "Ganesh" };

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("update messagesmaster set rstamp = 1 where mid in (");

int size = mlst.length;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    // adding the first quote
    sb.append("\"");
    // adding the word
    sb.append(mlst[i]);
    // adding the second quote
    sb.append("\"");

    // adding the comma
    if (i < (size - 1)) {
    sb.append(",");
    }
}

// closing
sb.append(");");

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```